# QField can't upload or package QGIS project

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qfield, qfieldsync

I'm trying to package and upload a project to the QField Cloud however it keeps failing.

First, I got this error:

> ERROR Project QField does not support projects configured to use absolute paths. Please change this configuration in "File -> Project settings" first."

However when I checked my project all my paths are relative.

The task will either fail or QGIS will crash entirely

Comment: This seems to be a bug repprt on Beta software,  and not a Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same issue and can't find a way on how to use QField 2.2. I downgraded to QField 2.1.4 bumble bee. I downgraded and tested everything and all is fine for me. Simply remove QField from your device, download the 2.1.4  version ( apk file) from here: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v2.1.4 onto your device. Click on the apk file, it will as you for permission, so follow the link to provide permission and then it will install. It took me less than 10 minutes.